# What are watch descriptors really ? (Linux inotify subsystem)

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm currently using the inotify() system for monitoring the activity of certain directories in the filesystem in my C code.

Now, the procedure for using one of these things is as follows. You take an integer(say event_notifier), turn it into an inotify descriptor using inotify_init(), like so

```
event_notifier=inotify_init();
```

Now, suppose I want to keep a watch over events on multiple directories. I will then add watches to this event_notifier over those directories

```
wd1 = inotify_add_watch(event_notifier,"/../path..to..directory1/../",IN_ALL_EVENTS);
wd2 = inotify_add_watch(event_notifier,"/../path..to..directory2/../",IN_ALL_EVENTS);
wd3 = inotify_add_watch(event_notifier,"/../path..to..directory3/../",IN_ALL_EVENTS);
                            . . . . 
wdn = inotify_add_watch(event_notifier,"/../path..to..directoryn/../",IN_ALL_EVENTS);
```

Now, I can add watches over multiple directories. Each of these calls returns a "watch descriptor" (wd1, wd2, wd3.. wdn above). Whenever an event occurs in any of the directories, the inotify system sends an event to the inotify file descriptor event_notifier along with the watch descriptor (wd1, wd2...wdn) corresponding to that particular "watched directory"

When an event comes in, I can read the event_notifier for an array of **struct inotify_event** s. This inotify_event structure has the following fields :

```
struct inotify_event  
{
  int wd; //Watch descriptor   
   ...  
  uint32_t len; //Size of 'name' field  
  char name[];  //null terminated name  
}
```

To read events, you simply do

```
read(event_notifier, buffer, sizeof(buffer))
struct inotify_event* event;
event=(struct inotify_event*)buffer; //Assuming only one event will occur
```

I am interested in finding out which directory the notification came from. But when I stat() the watch descriptor, it gives me nothing

```
struct stat fileinfo;
fstat(event->wd, &fileinfo);
printf("\n Size of file is %l",fileinfo_st.size);
```

Even readlink() on /proc/self/fd/event->fd did not yield any filename.

```
char filename[25]; 
readlink("/proc/self/fd/event-wd",filename,sizeof(filename));
printf("\n The filename is %s",filename);
```

I have two questions :

1) What is the watch descriptor pointing to exactly ? **What is it good for ?**
2) How can I tell **which directory the notification is coming from** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the watch descriptor pointing to exactly ? What is it good for ?

The watch descriptor isn't a file system object or a file descriptor. It is a resource descriptor used by the inotify subsystem to link events to a *watched* resource and gives you the possibility to specify certain watches when removing them.

You should also note that the number of possible "open" watch descriptors is limited on the system. You can get the maximum value using:

```
cat  /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

If you for any reason need more than this value, you can set the value using:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=XXXXXX
```

---

> How can I tell which directory the notification is coming from ?

Using the inotify extension only it is not possible to get the full path to the file (directory) from the event structures. Your application code will need special lookup tables storing links between watch descriptors and full path names. I did that once in PHP, because I also felt I needed that. You may have a look at the code on [Github](https://github.com/metashock/Jm_Os_Inotify). Like I said, it's PHP but it may help to understand what I'm doing. (The inotify system call signatures are the same in PHP and C)

Comment: Would it be accurate to say "The only thing watch descriptors are good for (on their own) is to remove watches" ?

Comment: They are required to remove watches, **and** linking them to full path names :) (or whatever metadata)

Comment: Yea. But we gotta do the linking part.  But, on their own, they are only good for removing watches. :)

Comment: Not really. Without them you wouldn't have any chance to link an event to a certain file or metadata. Since inotify only gives you the basename only you wouldn't know which file has changed if there are multiple files having the same name in different directories.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the watch descriptor pointing to exactly ?
  A file descriptor is not a pointer, it is an
  `int`
  .  Hence, it is incapable of pointing at anything.
  What is it good for ?
   A file descriptor abstract indicator for accessing a file.  With inotify, it is a reference to a virtual file.

The kernel maintains an array of structures (file descriptor table) with details of your process' files.  The file descriptor is an index into that array. Your process itself cannot read or write the file descriptor table directly.

How can I tell which directory the notification is coming from ?

Your application is responsible for associating the directory with the handle.

```
wd1 = inotify_add_watch(
   event_notifier,
   "/../path..to..directory1/../",
   IN_ALL_EVENTS
   );
```